# How to display data underground in cesium.js?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I want to display a polyline underground in cesium.js. But I have no idea about this.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you consulted the cesium.js docs about Polyline? https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Polyline.html?classFilter=polyL#Polyline

Comment: To help anyone else looking for this topic, here are a few links: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/P00xn5nIIHU and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176568/can-google-earth-be-used-to-display-underground-3d-structures/199476

Comment: And this as well https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/Z_bX7pr1sRg

Answer (score 2):

It seems that cesium has not provided official underground function for the reason that [cesium cameral can not be placed undergroud](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/P00xn5nIIHU),but the underground effect can be gained by an alternative way--`translucent terrain`.

According [How to display underground entity?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/M7cKgT1IEsw) in Cesium-dev google group,I have achieved **a barely satisfactory approach** to showing the entity(including gltf models) underground.The displaying effect is as what the GIF file shows.This appoach contains mainly 3 steps.

[image]
For gif, see [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xqYtcYpzusG0roZ56k3MCuO6fzQmDcdV).

**1.change only one line code in cesium source code**;get the cesium source code,then find the file named GlobeSurfaceTileProvider.js,change

```
command.pass = Pass.GLOBE;
```

to

```
command.pass = Pass.TRANSLUCENT;
```

**2.generate the cesium release code with gulp tool**;use your CLI to execute `gulp release`. PS： You may need set your node environment and install the dependency node modules and install gulp tool.

**3.Implemention code**.PS: note the following snippet can run only if you have changed the cesium source code which is illustrated in step one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Use correct character set. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Tell IE to use the latest, best version. -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Make the application on mobile take up the full browser screen and disable user scaling. -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <script src="../Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
    <style>
        @import url(../Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
        html,
        body,
        #cesiumContainer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        .tools {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="cesiumContainer">
        </div>
        <div class="tools">
            Opacity: <input id="btnImageryAlpha" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="10" oninput="change()" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function change() {
            var value = document.getElementById("btnImageryAlpha").value;
            if (viewer.imageryLayers) {
                for (var i = 0; i < viewer.imageryLayers.length; i++) {
                    viewer.imageryLayers.get(i).alpha = value / 10;
                }
            }
            console.log(value);
        }

        var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
            url: 'https://assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/v1/tilesets/world/tiles',
            requestVertexNormals: true
        });
        var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
            //skyAtmosphere: false,
            //orderIndependentTranslucency: false,
            baseLayerPicker: false,
            terrainProvider: terrainProvider
        });
        //viewer.scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = false;
        //change the ugly blue color to black
        viewer.scene.globe.baseColor = new Cesium.Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
        //default is 1
        //viewer.scene.globe.imageryLayers.get(0).alpha = 0.5;

        var blueBox = viewer.entities.add({
            name: 'Blue box',
            position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-114.0, 40.0, 5),
            box: {
                dimensions: new Cesium.Cartesian3(400000.0, 300000.0, 500000.0),
                material: Cesium.Color.BLUE
            }
        });

        viewer.zoomTo(blueBox);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: awesome. helpful

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is supported in cesium. It can be hard to see sometimes since the camera cannot go bellow the ellipsoid.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var purpleArrow = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Purple straight arrow at height',
    polyline : {
        positions : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([-75, 43, -200000,
                                                               -90, 43, -200000]),
        width : 10,
        followSurface : false,
        material : new Cesium.PolylineArrowMaterialProperty(Cesium.Color.PURPLE)
    }
});

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

[Live](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=9117a093f10137dcb91be9af47211112)